# Reshaping 3D DataArray into 2d DataArray

Tags: python, pandas, dask, python-xarray

I have `xarray dataarray` of the following shape.

`(10, 666, 999)` as `("band", "y", "x")`.

I want to get new `dataarray` into `(666*999, 10)` shape.
How can I solve it?

I tried as `ans = x_arr.transpose("y", "x", "band").reshape(666*999, 10)`

but it did not work.
`AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

reference, http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack` to combine existing dimensions into a new one. In your case it'd be something like `darr.stack(xy=["x", "y"])`

Here's a reproducible example:

```py
x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")
print(x.air.shape)
#(2920, 25, 53)

x2 = x.air.stack(point=["lat", "lon"])
print(x2.shape)
#(2920, 1325)
```

Comment: However, in my case, required output is, `(25*53, 2920)`.

Comment: just add `.transpose("point", ...)` in the end